# Django post text using submit button without using input tag

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates, jinja2

I have a django template in which there is a form in which I am getting input from the user.

**template.html**

```
{% extends 'header.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

    <h3> Questtion</h3>


    <img src="/media/{{ image }}" >
    <br> <br>
    <h3> Responses </h3>
<form  method="post" action="/tools/submit">
    {% csrf_token  %}
    <input type="text" name="first_response" placeholder="First Response"  size="40" required>
    <input type="text" name="second_response" placeholder="Second Response"  size="40" required> 
    <input type="text" name="third_response" placeholder="Third Response"  size="40" required> 
    <input type="text" name="fourth_response" placeholder="Fourth Response"  size="40" required>
    <input type="text" name="fifth_response" placeholder="Fifth Response"  size="40" required>

    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>   

{% endblock %}
```

The text from input is easy to get with the following method in **views.py**

```
def post_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_response = request.POST.get('first_response')
        second_response = request.POST.get('second_response')
        third_response = request.POST.get('third_response')
        fourth_response = request.POST.get('fourth_response')
        fifth_response = request.POST.get('fifth_response')
        image_name = # HOW TO GET {{ image }} name here ?
```

But I want to also post {{ image }} from `<img src="/media/{{ image }}" >` also when the submit button is clicked. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why do you want to POST something that is provided from the backend in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

in html

```
<form  method="post" action="/tools/submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Image Response"  size="40" required>
```

in view

```
fifth_response = request.FILES.get('image')
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your html template form add this line

```
<input type="hidden" name="question" value="/media/{{ image }}">
```

in Django views simply get the image path

```
fifth_response = request.POST.get('question')
```

since the image is already on your server i don't think you would like to have it as file. so getting file path is enough.